# Using Angular 1.X how can you persist the results of an $http request across controllers?

Tags: angularjs, persistence

I've read multiple places that you can share data across controllers with services/providers/factories. Maybe I interpreted the results of these incorrectly but from what I understand services/providers/factories are an abstraction that can be rerun across controllers providing the same data.

I'd like to get result from a database query once without making the same request over again across different controllers. Do services/providers/factories do this or do I need something like ngStorage or localStorage? Or is there another way I'm not thinking of? I saw a mention of making an initial query at start-up (.run?) but I'm not really sure to get started with that.

Comment: *"Do services/providers/factories do this"* ~ Yes. Providers in Angular are singletons so they are all the same instance across the different consumers (controllers, etc). You can store data in them that will last in memory

Comment: @Phil, thanks then what are things like ngStorage and localStorage for if the data can be saved and persisted in a factory? Moreover, how are they the same instance if they can provide different results if you pass them different arguments?

Comment: The factory only lasts as long as you have the page open and don't reload or navigate away (ie, **in memory**). Local storage persists outside this range. I don't really understand your second question; the return values of factory methods can of course be different based on what you pass in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarise from my comments above...

> *"I'd like to get result from a database query once without making the same request over again across different controllers. Do services/providers/factories do this..."*

Yes. Providers in Angular are singletons so they are all the same instance across the different consumers (controllers, etc). You can store data in them that will last **in memory**.

A factory only lasts as long as you have the page open and don't reload or navigate away whereas something like local storage persists outside this range.

---

Here's an example making an HTTP query on app startup (ie, opening / reloading the page) that can be shared across controllers and other consumers

```js
angular.module('so', [])

.factory('sharedData', function($http) {
  // this factory is a promise  
  return $http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
    .then(res => res.data);
})

.controller('someController', function(sharedData) {
  sharedData.then(post => {
    this.post = post;
  });
})

.controller('anotherController', function(sharedData) {
  sharedData.then(post => {
    this.post = post;
  });
});
```

```html
<div ng-app="so">
  <dl ng-controller="someController as s">
    <dt>Post title</dt>
    <dd>{{s.post.title || 'Loading...'}}</dd>
    <dt>Post body</dt>
    <dd>{{s.post.body || 'Loading...'}}</dd>
  </dl>
  
  <pre ng-controller="anotherController as a">post = {{a.post|json}}</pre>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the details. In my case I didn't need it past the statements you and Sergey provided but newbies will be very greatful; I was one not to long ago.

Answer (score 1):

That depends. If you looking for the way to load data only once per application session (e.g. between application bootstrap and window reload/close/navigate outside) services going to be a solution for you. But if you looking for the solution that will also store your data between sessions you need to rely on some browser storage solution inside of your services.

Comment: Thanks Sergey. I think the key words I was looking for is "between sessions". That makes all of the difference in the world and is the nuance I think I was looking for. I have to wonder, was this question so bad it deserves a minus? Really this a detail not readily discernable . . . I guess. Smh.

Comment: I guess it's all about you question being too broad. I am personally don't feel like it suppose to be downvoted but may be downvoters drop a comment about their reasons?

Comment: It would be nice to know where I went wrong. Given the answer I was looking for, I'd definitely like to know where I went wrong in asking this question.